# Substring column values that exceed 4000 characters

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a column (URL) with URL values with a varchar2(4000) data type. Some of the values in there exceed 4000 characters, so is there a way for me to substring only those values in the column that exceed 4000 characters replacing the original value with the substring within that same column?

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but I'm sceptical about the fact that you think you have > 4000 characters in a varchar2(4000) column. The maximum number of characters you can have in the column already is 4000..

Answer (score 2):

You are able find out the columns that exceeds 4000 characters like this,

```
select userid, length(description)
from Users
where length(description) > 4000;
```

So the resolution you can do it in the CTL file itself as follows,

```
description "SUBSTR(:description, 1, 4000)",
```

If you don want to loose data then you can use `CLOB` datatype instead of `varchar2(4000)`

Comment: Yes, I've tried CLOB datatype, but I need this data for text mining, and apparently CLOB datatype isn't taken into account during the modeling process, neither is nvarchar2 for that matter.

Comment: Then you will end up wit error as long as you use varchar2. But you can restrict the data using substring. As you want that data for text mining, you should have a temp table wit CLOB datatype.

Comment: Or another way, you can write a trigger to store those records in a temp table (either split them or have CLOB datatype)

Answer (score 2):

Varchar supports up to 4,000 characters; each and every function output, like SUBSTR, is a varchar so will not able to hold more than a 4,000 character string. You will have use a clob; but a clob is a lobobject; so, it will be slow.

You could, while creating the table, add 2 columns and use a PL/SQL block as a varchar can be up to 32,767 characters in PL/SQL.